# How to debug a "hidden" function in an R package?

Tags: r, function, debugging

can someone please help me understand this:
I encountered an error when calling a function from a library, specifically "steinertree" from the "SteinerNet" package. When stepping into the function with `debug(steinertree)`, I see that the error occurs, when the function in turn calls "`steinertree3`". When I try `debug(steinertree3)`, I get "object 'steinertree3' not found". Similarly, I can get the code for '`steinertree`' by typing it in the terminal, but not for '`steinertree3`'.
So it seems to me that there are some "higher-level" functions and "hidden" functions in packages. I did eventually find the error by finding a file "steinertree.R" in the package at CRAN, which contains both '`steinertree`' and '`steinertree3`', but I`m wondering how to properly go about debugging such "hidden" functions.

Here is a simple example:

```
library(igraph)
library(SteinerNet)

set.seed(1)
g= erdos.renyi.game(n=10,p.or.m=0.2)
plot(g)
steinertree(type= 'KB', terminals= c(1,3), graph= g)
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can expose hidden functions with a *triple* colon: `package:::hidden_function`

Comment: Ben, too late. Will remember next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use triple colon `:::` to execute a function that is not exported by the package/namespace:

```
package:::hidden_function()
```

Comment: Perhaps an alternative is,  when inside the debugger for `steinertree` , type `debug(steinertree3)`  . Depending on what is loaded by the parent function, this may suffice.